# how to estimate bright channel for color image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, brightness

how to estimate the bright channel prior for color image (convert the image of the spatial domain into Brightness Domain) using the following formula:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBTNa.png)
Does anyone know how to do this in Matlab??

Answer (score 0):

One would need to know more about what Omega(x) is but I'm guessing it's a local window.  Code like what's below is a start (replace 1:2 and 4:6 with your window):

`[bright, bright_channel_idx] = max( image(1:2,4:6,:), [], 3 ); % take the max along the 3rd dimension, color`

Comment: this is the form of estimating bright channel. where Ic is a color channel of I and Ω(x) is a local patch centered at x. y is a pixel in the local path Ω(x). the bright channel is the outcome of two maximum operators. The operator "max c∈{r,g,b}” is performed on each pixel for the three channels. The operator “max y∈Ω(x)” is a maximum filter. the local patch size for both operation was set as 15 × 15. so, i asked about how to do this in matlab?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a block of code to get you started.  You can use two for loops to go over the rows (r) and columns (c).  There must be faster ways of doing this but this is enough to get you started.  Another hint: be careful when your for loops gets near the end of rows and/or columns.

```
      block_r = img( r:r+kernel_h, c:c+kernel_w, 1 ); % get a region
      block_g = img( r:r+kernel_h, c:c+kernel_w, 2 );
      block_b = img( r:r+kernel_h, c:c+kernel_w, 3 );

      max_r = max( block_r(:) ); % max within each region
      max_g = max( block_g(:) );
      max_b = max( block_b(:) );

      bright_img(r,c) = max( [max_r,max_g,max_b] ); % max across all channels
```